# Movie with wormlike creatures in an island which enter and consume human bodies; they don't survive saltwater

Tags: story-identification, movie

This movie is about worm/leeches that enter the human body. At first the person feels better and maybe with abilities but the worms continue to grow and multiply until they consume the host. And they are unable to survive salt water. I watched it a long time ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Growth* (2010)?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_(film)):

> In 1989 on Cuttyhunk Island, scientist Mason Lane used **microscopic parasites to advance human evolution. The experiment resulted in stronger, smarter, healthier humans**, but something went wrong and three quarters of the island's residents died. [...]
>
> For a long time, the project saw fruitful results, but then realized that the humans started suffering since the parasites had to feed. **He mentions that every parasite's weakness has been salt and shows by putting one of the human parasites in a solution of salt water.**

---

Found with the Google query `movie worms enter human bodies vulnerable saltwater` which brought up the Wikipedia page.

Comment: thanks. it is exactly what I was looking for